# How do I grab the subtopics of a given topic in the Napili community template from within a custom lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, napili

I'm trying to create a custom lightning component version of the headline component for the Napili community template, and I would like to link to the subtopics of the chosen topic, but I'm unable to find a way to get these. Does anyone know of a way to grab the subtopics of a selected topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact term for this is known as **"Managed Topics"**.

You can use ConnectAPI namespace of Apex to fetch related Child Topics for a [managed Topic](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_managed_topic.htm)

```
System.debug(ConnectAPI.ManagedTopics.getManagedTopics('0DB90000000PBQt', ConnectApi.ManagedTopicType.Navigational));
```

Use the above to get hold of All Navigational Topics

And now use the Id of the ManagedTopics to get more info around them ,like below

And then for each Managed Topic extract more info using below

```
 System.debug(ConnectAPI.ManagedTopics.getManagedTopic('0DB90000000PBQt', '0mt90000000PAtVAAW', 2));
```

> '0DB90000000PBQt' is the Community or network Id .You can obtain using [Network class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_network.htm)